# Cannot remove docker images without tags/<none> tags

Tags: awk, grep, docker, delete-file, image-file

I am using [docker](https://www.docker.com/), and I have found that when I run a

```
docker images -a
```

I have an enormous number of images without tags, or at least they have a tag of

```
<none>
```

These are wasting way too much space on my disk, and now a df -h tells me that my root is full.

I lurked around the internet and found that

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Will at least iterate through all of the none's, but then I get a whole slew of error messages.

```
Error: response from daemon: Conflict, <id> wasn't deleted
Error: response from daemon: Conflict, <id> wasn't deleted 
Error: response from daemon: Conflict, <id> wasn't deleted
Error: response from daemon: Conflict, <id> wasn't deleted 
etc...
Error: failed to remove images: [<list of all the image ids that I want gone>]
```

This is getting to be somewhat annoying. Does anyone know what these none tagged images are, and why my command isn't getting rid of them?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you build a new version of a tagged image (e.g., you run `docker build -t foo .`, change something in the Dockerfile, and then run the command again), the older image isn't deleted; it just gets its tag taken away.  The `<none>`s you see are images without any tags left, and you can refer to them in commands by specifying their image ID (`fe336c4cdb2f` or whatever).  You can thus delete them by passing these IDs to `docker rmi`, or you can do this:

```
docker images -f dangling=true -q | xargs -r docker rmi
```

If you still get error messages about being unable to delete images, it may be that there are still containers hanging around that use these old images; check by running `docker ps -a`.

Comment: There are no more containers, I was able to kill all of those off.

Comment: actually there does appear to be one when I run a docker ps -a, but I cannot kill it for some reason. It will acknowledge my "docker stop <id>", but then when I check again, it is still there

Comment: @Zack: `docker stop` doesn't remove containers; you need `docker rm` for that.

Comment: ok sorry, yea, I just did that. It removed the container. I tried the command you gave me now, and it didn't kill off the none tags

Answer (score 3):

Those `<none>` in REPOSITORY when you specifically do `docker images -a` are **not** meant to be deleted. Those are the internal layers that make up your image.

As suggested by @jwodder, you should delete the `<none>`ones which appear when you do `docker images` ( Note: I did not do `-a` ). If you see `<none>` in REPOSITORY when you do `docker images`, then you could do:
`docker rmi -f $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)`

If your disk space is full, try removing the images that you do not need and see when you do `docker images`, not with `-a`.